# How do I customize the output of the <s:fieldError /> tag?

Tags: java, struts2, struts

How do I get the validation messages I set using the struts2 validation:

```
public void validate() {
    addFieldError("user", "Invalid User");
}
```

I want to get the "Invalid User" and "user" strings from a custom tagLib to print like:

```
public int doStartTag() {
    pageContext.getOut().print( "Invalid User - user" )
}
```

UPDATE:
The example was a reduced and non-functional usage just explaining how I would like the values to be returned not exactly how I would use it, but here is the use case:

I want to create a custom tagLib that prints the error from struts validation. In a single tagLib I want to verify if the page contains a validation error for a given input then print in the screen the content of the error.

Scriptlet, <logic:*, javascript -> it is all out of question.

If the jsp is meant to hold the structure of the document a taglib with internal specific rules makes much more sense than flooding the page with logic comparisons.

I am not using `<s:fieldError />` (or smth like that) because it create an `ul` and `li` structure I cant get rid of, even setting the default template as "simple"

Comment: Don't have time to look into this too much but in past experience building on a struts2 tag worked okay (I remember thinking the inheritance hierarchy was a bit much). Extending the strut2 fielderror tag would be a good start. If you explain your use-case there might be a much easier way... My need for creating a tag was to dynamically determine how to render an object based on its type. That was sufficiently weird that a tag was required, but just printing "Invalid User - user" does not seem to warrant a custom tag.

Comment: If you want to remove `ul` and `li` elements from `<s:fielderror>` tag then creating custom library is overkill. Just modify `<s:fielderror>` tag template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aleksandr M is correct.  If you only want to change the markup spit out by the tag, you definitely don't want to create a tag, you only want to override the template that is rendering it.  This is quite easy.  You will get a copy of the template from the struts core jar, edit it, and put it in your project.  Here's a link to the docs:

http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/template-loading.html

Note, depending on what you want to do, you could just get the error messages yourself.  They are all exposed as JavaBeans properties on ActionSupport, which your actions should inherit from, and you can reach them with OGNL expressions, such as in the property tag.

Note, ActionSupport implementst these to fullfil the contract of the ValidationAware interface which it implements.

Comment: So there is no way to access the validation message outside the built-in tagLib?

Comment: No, that's not accurate either.  You can get them with OGNL expressions from anywhere in the result.  I'll add that option to my answer.